# My laptop and my phone top out at 40 Mbps on my home WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, internet-connection

So I recently got myself a 50 Mbps down / 5 Mbps up internet connection. I'm very happy with it, except both my MacBook Air and my iPhone 5S top out at about 40-42 Mbps down speed. My PC which has a USB WiFi adapter (TP-Link TL-WN722N), tops out at 50-51 Mbps on the same network, which is exactly how fast my internet is, so that's how I know that there's something wrong with the other two devices. Even if I take my laptop and my phone and stand next to my router for maximum signal strength, they still top out at 40-ish Mbps down. Although 40 Mbps would still be fast enough for me, I still don't understand it.

My router is a TP-Link TL-WR741ND, and my WiFi network is 802.11b/g/n mixed, 2.4Ghz / 20 Mhz, WPA2-Personal AES encryption, channel 11 fixed. Since I have another router that connects to this one via WDS, I need to have a fixed channel, so I set it to 11. There are a couple of other WiFi networks around, but they are either channel 1 or 6, that's why I'm on 11, so interference problems should not happen at all.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Sounds like phone and laptop can only do 802.11g which is 50Mbps. With encryption overhead and all things considered, you're doing about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did a bit of research, and I know what's wrong here. Apple does not allow 40 Mhz or "bonded channel" mode in 2.4 Ghz mode in their devices. So even if one's router is capable of 40 Mhz mode in 2.4 Ghz, an Apple device will only use half of that (they do support 40 Mhz in 5 Ghz mode though).
What this means is that whatever bandwidth your router is advertised with, you're going to get half (or less) of it. In my case, my router is advertised to deliver 150 Mbps. In 20 Mhz mode, that translates to roughly 75 Mbps, but because of other factors, real-world connection speed is 65 Mbps. WPA2 encryption does eat up a good percentage of that, so that is why my connection tops out at a 40-ish Mbps speed.

Solution:
Buying a 300 Mbps 802.11n router. Since that's capable of 300 Mbps in 40 Mhz mode, it will roughly deliver 150 Mbps even in 20 Mhz mode. So even if you count the WPA2 overhead, that's still a lot faster than the 150 Mbps router in 20 Mhz mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the bandwidth of your signal from 20 to 40mhz. You can tell us the models of your phone and laptop if you can't find out if they support 802.11n, but why wouldn't they? My luggable laptop is getting to be a legacy item, yet it has n.

Comment: They do support 802.11n of course. 2012 MacBook Air and an iPhone 5S. I can't change to 40mhz though, it always falls back to 20 because of interference I guess.

Comment: This is very interesting... I read that Apple only allows 20 mhz on 2.4 Ghz wireless connections. So maybe my router does in fact use 40 mhz, but my Apple devices only use half of that (which allows for 65 Mbps minus the overhead of course), while the PC with the external wireless antenna receives full 40 mhz channel width. I think this is the problem here.

Comment: Btw, enabling 'interference robustness' on my old 11g airport express always gave a bigger hit to speed than any interference could, except a nuclear blast. I think something as prominent as appleware would be capable of using 40mhz - do you have a link for this? Only now do I see I am commenting on my own post :(

Comment: just anecdotally, as I've never really investigated it - my 5S won't work if I switch my APs to 40MHz only. I used to be able to get about 65Mb down on iOS 7 but don't seem to get over 40 since iOS 8. It's fast enough for me, so I haven't really figured out why.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, considering the price and brand. I dont have fiber, so I would never have noticed.

Comment: There's a good reason why it's not supported. First of all, the 802.11n specification does not include support for 40 Mhz in 2.4 Ghz mode, so the devices that support it are going against it. Also, the 2.4 Ghz frequency is cluttered with all kinds of things (95% of WiFi networks, bluetooth, RC cars, whatever... just name it, and it works over 2.4 Ghz). Therefore, there's lot of interference, so taking up two channels in 2.4 Ghz instead of one is not a good idea. Seems like Apple thinks the same way. They kind of encourage you to use 5 Ghz, which has a lot less interference.